# Randomly pick k bits out of n from a Java BitSet

Tags: java, algorithm

How to pick exactly `k` bits from a [Java BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) of length `m` with `n` bits turned on, where `k≤n≤m`?

Example input: `m=20, n=11`
[image]

Example output: `k=3`
[image]

#### The naive approach

Choose a random number `0≤ i ≤ m-1`.if it's turned on on the input and not turned on on the output, turn it on in the output, until `k` bits are turned on in the output.

This approach fails when `n` is much smaller than `m`. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could scan the set from the first bit to the last, and apply [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to the bits that are set.

The algorithm has `O(m)` time complexity, and requires `O(k)` memory.

Answer (score 1):

If the constraints allow it you can solve the task by:

Construct a `List` holding all the set bits indexes. Do `Collections#shuffle` on it. Choose the first `k` indexes from the shuffled list.

**EDIT** As per the comments this algorithm can be inefficient if `k` is really small, whilst `n` is big. Here is an alternative: generate `k` random, different numbers in the interval `[0, n]`. If in the generation of a number the number is already present in the set of chosen indices, do the chaining approach: that is increase the number by 1 until you get a number that is not yet present in the set. Finally the generated indices are those that you choose amongst the set bits.

Comment: It's inefficient for small `k` and large `n` values.

Comment: @AdamMatan I am not totally sure. The alternative with random probation can result in infinite loop with small n. The complexity of my approach is `O(m)` both in memory and time. You can not reduce the time if you want the algorithm to be really random. You can reduce the memory for small `k` probably. I will try to edit with this improvement.

Comment: Thanks, Boris - Memory improvements would be great.

Comment: Boris, The second approach isn't random because it favors sparse bits over dense clusters. Consider `000000001000000011111`. The leftmost bit has more chances of being picked than the ones clustered in the right chunk.

Comment: @AdamMatan nope I consider only the set bits, thus I generate `k` random numbers upto `n`, not `m`.

Answer (score 1):

How about finding `n` positions of all set bits and placing them in a collection as the first step, and them choosing `k` positions from that collection randomly?

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is much larger than `k`, you can just pare down the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm to stop after you've chosen as many as you need:

```
private static Random rand = new Random();
public static BitSet chooseBits(BitSet b, int k) {
    int n = b.cardinality();
    int[] indices = new int[n];
    // collect indices:
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++) {
        j=b.nextSetBit(j);
        indices[i] =j++;
    }
    // create returning set:
    BitSet ret = new BitSet(b.size());
    // choose k bits:
    for (int i = 0; i<k; i++) {
        //The first n-i elements are still available.
        //We choose one:
        int pick = rand.nextInt(n-i);
        //We add it to our returning set:
        ret.set(indices[pick]);
        //Then we replace it with the current (n-i)th element
        //so that, when i is incremented, the 
        //first n-i elements are still available:
        indices[pick] = indices[n-i-1];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: The memory complexity os O(n), right? It's inefficient for very large values of `n` where `k` is very small.

Comment: @AdamMatan Yes, reservoir sampling seems like the way to go so long as your prng is very fast, since you'd call it `m-k` times. If it isn't, you could just choose `k` values in `[0..n)`, skipping duplicates (`k/n` is approx. 0, so this is efficient), into a sorted set. Then the only thing you'd need to do at the `m` scale would be counting set bits, and noting whenever your count is in your set of random values. Obtaining `n` could be problematic, as it would require an extra pass to count.